# Deleting individual byte in a memory field (array)

Tags: c++, memory, pointers

I have an array.

```
int count=5;

char * array;
array=new char[count];

//now I want to do this:

delete[1]->array+1;
delete[1]->array+3;
```

how do I go about doing that?

the freed memory can no longer be associated with the program, however array+0, array+2& array+4 need to remain locked in.

I want to have a shared memory bloc that is not associated with any program which can be used by any program without special privileges.

the point of doing this would be to prevent the system from allocating this section to another program, or at least reducing the probability it does so.

Comment: You mean remove the characters at the given index?

Comment: no. i want to free the memory.

Comment: You only allocated 1 block of memory in your example. Did you want each character to be allocated individually?

Comment: why do you want to do this? If you tell us we might be able to suggest alternative ways to archieve what you want.

Comment: btw: keep in mind that C/C++ (and anything else for that matter) does dynamic memory allocation using extra memory to keep track of the allocated blocks, something like ([size, next] yourdata), ([size1, next1] yourdata1), ([size2, next2] yourdata2)... this is oversimplified but I hope you get the idea, these structures are more than 1-2 bytes you are trying to free here.

Answer (score 4):

You can not delete elements in C/C++ arrays.

You can however have an array of pointers and allocate memory only for the needed elements, the rest can be NULL. This however changes the definition, it's no longer an array of characters, it's an array of pointers to characters.

What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

As other suggested, strictly speacking, you ask a single block (`count` element wide) to the system, and you cannot give it back in chunks.
Also, it is not clear if you want to preserve the indexes of the remaining block or not.

You actually have this:

```
 addr.        a b c d e    
|____| ----> |_|_|_|_|_|
array         0 1 2 3 4
```

You can have this:

```
 addr.        a c e
|____|-----> |_|_|_|
array         0 1 2
```

By performing another allocation, copy the value to preserve, and give the first block back.

Otherwise you have to change the whole model as

```
|____|----->|____|____|____|____|____|
               |    |    |    |    |
               V    V    V    V    V
              |_|  |_|  |_|  |_|  |_|
```

So that it can be changed as

```
|____|----->|____|____|____|____|____|
               |    |    |    |    |
               V    V    V    V    V
              |_|   x   |_|   x   |_|
```

But this means play with pointer to pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this if you use the `new[]` operator to allocate your array.  What you need to do is use `malloc()` to allocate your array, use `memmove()` to remove the byte, use `realloc()` to reallocate your array to its size minus one, and later on use `free()` to free your array.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would recommend you **don't** allocate memory explicitly in the first place! The `new` and `delete` operators are overused, especially by C++ beginners. I consider myself a reasonably advanced C++ users and I rarely use either of these operators in my code. If I do, I'm implementing some rather low-level code. Instead you would use e.g. an `std::string` which supports functions to remove elements from the middle:

```
std::string array(count);
array.erase(array.begin() + 1);
array.erase(array.begin() + 3);
```

Comment: i'm looking to control the physical memory though. string erase just rearranges the array of pointers if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: No operating system controls memory allocation on a byte level. They all use pages at minimum. On top of the page abstraction, memory allocation facilities use their own blocks of memory allocated. ... and getting to "physical" memory is pretty much impossible. Maybe it would help if you explained **what** you actually want to do rather then **how** you think it would be done.